# Postman GET Request hangs and never returns any results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, postman

I am attempting to Build A REST API With Node.js, Express, & MongoDB. Everything seem to work so far. The server starts and connects to the DB. The DB (named API) has two collections (Articles and Sources). I am trying to send GET request to the Articles collection. However, when I send the request, Postman sort of hangs and then gives this an error and crashes the server:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to localhost:3000/articles.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

The server throws the following error(s) when it crashes:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10007e891 node::Abort() [/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x10007e9c0 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x10017e6ab v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node]
```

My code looks like the following:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express') 
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'))

app.use(express.json())

const articlesRouter = require('./routes/articles')
app.use('/articles', articlesRouter)

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Started'))
```

My routes; I'm attempting to send GET request to get All the articles in the DB (that are in the Articles collection):

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Article = require('../models/articles')

//Getting All Articles
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const articles = await Article.find()
      res.json(articles)
  } catch (err){
    res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
  }
})

//Getting One Article
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

})

module.exports = router
```

If I change the `router.get` to this `router.get('/articles', async (req, res)` Postman will no longer hang, but throw the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /articles</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

And my routes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const articlesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String, content: String, description: String, publishedAt: Date, source_id: String, summarization: String, title: String, url: String, urlToImage: String}, { collection: 'Articles'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('article', articlesSchema)
```

As I mentioned in the beginning, this is my first attempt at building a REST API. Any help you can provide to help me figure out why a Postman GET request isn't going through, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The server throws JavaScript heap out of memory, would be await Article.find() returning too many records?

Comment: Idk... Possibly I guess. I add a limit of 10 results to the GET request in Postman though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct. 
One thing that i had encounter is in your route you specify only

```
`router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{})`
```

and you are calling api as 
"`localhost:3000/articles`" which is incorrect. 
you haven't specify any route as

`router.get('/articles', async (req, res) =>{})`.

so postman not able to find such route and respond none. 
Try with route which i have specify above or call only "`localhost:3000/`" as you specify in routes.

Other thing you can do is just put following line in your **app.js** file and no need to change anything else in your code.

```
app.use('/articles', articlesRouter)
```

Hope this help you out.

Comment: I tired both `router.get('/articles', async (req, res) =>{})` and `app.use('/articles', articlesRouter)` the good thing now is that postman no longer hangs, instead it gives me this error `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot GET /articles</pre>
</body>

</html>`

Comment: Don't use both solutions all at once. either try to change in app.js or try to change in routes.

Comment: I changed it in app.js and the result is still the same